# jquery on click appear another element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for example I have this html code:

```
<div class="product">
    <p>Name1<p>
</div>
<div class="product">   
    <p>Name2<p>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <p>Name3<p>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <p>Name4<p>
</div>
<div class="settings">
    <p>SETTINGS<p>
</div>
```

I made settings class to display nothing in css, unless I click on one of 4 p elements in product class. After click the settings class appears at the bottom as it should be.

How should I make that if I click for example Name2 then settings class appears after Name2 and not at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to target the element you clicked on, combined with `insertAfter()` to add the content to this element.

Run the code snippet below and click on any of the elements with the classname `product` to see how this works.

```
$(".product").click(function(){
    $(".settings").insertAfter($(this));
});
```

```js
    $(".product").click(function(){
       $(".settings").insertAfter($(this));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <p>Name1
    <p>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p>Name2
    <p>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p>Name3
    <p>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p>Name4
    <p>
</div>
<div class="settings">
  <p>SETTINGS
    <p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.insertAfter()` :

```js
$(function(){
  $('.product p').click(function(){
    $('.settings').insertAfter($(this).closest('.product '))
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
    <p>Name1<p>
</div>
<div class="product">   
    <p>Name2<p>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <p>Name3<p>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <p>Name4<p>
</div>
<div class="settings">
    <p>SETTINGS<p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like,

```
$(".product > p").click(function(){
 var $parent = $(this).parent(".product");
 $parent.siblings(".settings").insertAfter($parent);
});
```

by using [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2ts9ohc7/)